# How to detect which ListPickerItem is selected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this code for my ListPicker in my WP7 Application,

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listTab1" Header="Muti-View 1 Settings"  Margin="428,220,112,25.51" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.RenderTransform>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="tab 1"/>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="tab 2"/>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="tab 3"/>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I need to detect which Which Listpicker item is selected, in the Listpicker so i can use it in an If statement

Any Ideas in which i can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `ListPicker`  `SelectionChanged` event. At first we will get a reference to the current `SelectedItem` data object  and after that we will get a reference to the `SelectedItem` container which is of type `ListPickerItem`.:

```
private void listPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //Get the data object that represents the current selected item
   SampleData data = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as SampleData;

   //Get the selected ListPickerItem container instance    
   ListPickerItem selectedItem = this.listPicker.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListPickerItem;
}
```

[Source](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/working-with-wp7-listpicker-selecteditem)